# How do I load custom "const" variables from a config file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, config

I currently have a function which loads variables from a config file. It uses these to initialise a set of constant config variables.

```
// header file
namespace cfg {
    extern const char *config_value;
}

// source file 
namespace cfg {
    const char *config_value;
}

bool load_config() {
    cfg::config_value = load_config_line("config_value");
}

const char *load_config_line(const char *key) {
       // read value from config.cfg...
}
```

This works pretty well. The problem is that now I want to reuse this code in several other projects, which means the constant values have to change. This means changing the `config_value` names in four different places each in the code. It also means I have several copies of essentially the same code to maintain in different projects.

**Is there a way of setting  different sets of constant values using the same code for the reading and parsing?** Perhaps so that all I have to do is change the header file and it automatically finds those value names in the config file? The tricky part is that ideally the **outward facing config values themselves should be constant and available at compile time** (using a string to value map for example is undesirable, as I would prefer to have the compile time protection).

Comment: You should use an already implemented "serializer" and store and reload data to struct/class instances instead of reinventing the wheel and deal with global vars.

Comment: @Klaus sorry can you elaborate on "serializer"?

Comment: Please use your favorite search engine :-) There a a lot of libraries which provide a way to read/write data from c++ data structures to files/network/data base. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0_b1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to not use global variables, and instead have some `settings` struct which you explicitly initialize with values loaded from the file. The struct instance itself doesn't need to be const (you'll need to be able to load the values into it, unless you pass everything in on construction), but all access to it should be `const`. This last bit can be achieved by passing `settings` as e.g. a `const settings&` to wherever it is needed.

```
int main()
{
    // Variant A: 2-step init
    settings s;
    s.loadConfigFile(filename);
    // Variant B: 1-step init - can make instance itself const
    const settings s(filename);

    Thing worker(s); // Thing::Thing(const settings&)
    worker.work();
}
```

Of course `Worker` can be anything your heart desires.

Note that settings itself needs no special constness whatsoever:

```
struct settings
{
    std::string config_value;
}
```

It is the external `const` that guards access to the values contained within.

Comment: thats usefull, it gets me part way there. However I'll still need to write `loadConfigFile` function for each new `struct settings` (in different projects)? Thats what im trying to avoid. I need a `loadConfigFile(settings set, std::string filename)` which will take any arbitrary structure

Comment: @Drgabble if you need any arbitrary structure, you'l need to store the settings as e.g. a `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>` or `std::unordered_map<string, boost::variant<int,double, std::string>>` or whatever. If there is structure, you need to decide if you want separate `settings` structs for each configuration structure. Its a runtime vs programtime trade-off.

Comment: there's no way of having separate `settings` structs with the same `loadConfig()` function then? Yes I'm trying to get the best of both worlds here I guess... there's no reflection-type way of doing this then? Or am I thinking in Java too much?

Comment: @Drgabble This code already works with an arbitrary structure. But really, don’t implement this yourself, use an existing INI, [YAML](http://yaml.org/), [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml) library.

Comment: @Drgabble There are many ways to tackle this problem. I suggest you ask a detailed question to get a proper response. Right now we're all just guessing and suggesting stuff that might not even be necessary.